# Comparing results from two different sub queries in SQL

Tags: php, postgresql, relational-database

So I have two different queries. The first query gathers the results which are being searched by the search and combined them with the result set of the second query. What I am trying to do is do the following with the time results that are being displayed. So something like treating my first query as X, and the second query as Y. Then doing the time comparison which goes something like this 
     WHERE X.time> Y.time

Am just a little unsure if I can use the aliases w1 and w2 to accomplish this.
Just to clear there is a start destination name, start time and end destination name and end time.

Comment: May you provide a SQLfiddle? http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: The query is fine. Its just the results it provides. For example in the first query gives the times:

Query1: X Depart : 09:07:00  X Arrival : 10:19:00  
Query 2: Y Depart: 09:18:00  Y Arrival: 10:36:00

The results from Y dont make sense. I want to basically make sure that the values from the first query X are always bigger than the values from the query Y @DylanSu

Comment: Could you take a look at  the link I have provided. It will be too long to put in the sqlfiddle: 
@Reversal

Comment: How about adding a WHERE clause at the end of the query? Append `WHERE w1.time1 > w2.time3 AND w1.time2 > w2.time4`

Comment: What I am confused on where this statement should be inserted @Reversal

Comment: `SELECT [..] FROM ( [..] ) w1 JOIN ( [..] ) w2 USING (rn) WHERE w1.time1 > w2.time3 AND w1.time2 > w2.time4;`

Comment: That's not worked at all and provided no results @Reversal

Comment: What's the error you got then?

Comment: Just checked my error log and I have no error showing up @Reversal

Comment: `row_number() OVER () AS rn` is basically a random ordering. Just saying...

Comment: So what am I supposed to be doing with my query @Strawberry.

Comment: The row_number function is allowing me join the query results together by assigning a row number to each record @joop

Comment: My proposal seems to work properly to me. If you are stuck with this problem consider again providing a SQL fiddle. Give us an example dataset and table schema and maybe we will help you better. If you don't want to invest some time of yours to let us help you then I'm sorry, we can't do much more.